ExceptionFilter is skipped on model validation errors
I'm trying to have my custom ExceptionFilterAttribute execute also in case of model validation errors.
Currently its getting skipped and I'm getting following response for example:
{
    "type":"https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.1",
    "title":"One or more validation errors occurred.",
    "status":400,
    "traceId":"0HN2SGEJJ6355:00000004",
    "errors":{
        "scope":[
            "The Scope field is required."
        ],
        "xxx":[
            "The XXX field is required."
        ]
    }

My filter, no hint on the OnException method:
public class ApiExceptionFilterAttribute : ExceptionFilterAttribute
{
      public override void OnException(ExceptionContext context)
      {
            // ...
      }
}

Registered as follows:
services.AddControllers(options => options.Filters.Add<ApiExceptionFilterAttribute>())

Using dotnet 7.

Exception filters work for exceptions. Model validation error is not an exception, so yes, your exception filter is skipped. This is by design and working as intended.

You should use ActionFilterAttribute instead of ExceptionFilterAttribute.
According to Microsoft, action filters run before and after the action method execution. It uses to validate incoming data, implementing caching or modify the HTTP respose include header, status codes and etc...
Exception Filter:
Apply global policies to unhandled exceptions that occur before the response body has been written to.
It's used to provide custom exception handling logic, such as logging the error, returning specific error responses, or performing cleanup tasks before responding to the client.
Remember to suppress the model state invalid filter in Program.cs, just like the example below:
builder.Services.Configure<ApiBehaviorOptions>(options =>
       options.SuppressModelStateInvalidFilter = true);

And create a ValidateModelAttribute class. For instance
public class ValidateModelAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
    {
        public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
        {
            if (!context.ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                var details = new ValidationProblemDetails(context.ModelState)
                {
                    Detail = "Validatio Error",
                    Type = "https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.1"
                };

                context.Result = new BadRequestObjectResult(details);
            }
        }
    }

and at the end add it in program.cs:
builder.Services.AddControllers(o=>o.Filters.Add<ValidateModelAttribute>());

